# Python: How to iterate an n-dimensional matrix?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a matrix with shape (1 , 255, 13, 13), so I have 13x13=169 elements and for each of this elements I have a array of 255 elements.

I want to iterate over the fourth element of the 255 array and count how many elements are greater than 0.5.

This code doesn't work but help to understand what I want:

```
out = net.forward()

count1=0
count2=0

for i in out[0]:
    for j in out[2]:
        for a in out[3]:
            for b in out[1]:
                if b[3]> 0.5:

                    count1+=1
                else:
                    count2+=1
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your code snippet is not complete since you do not define your `net` module or object. I do not "understand what [you] want." Please show the definition. The "best way" depends greatly on the data structure. If you are so concerned about the performance of a large matrix, you should probably be using numpy.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly:

```
def give_counts(out):
    """Count the fourth element of each cell if it is >0.5

    >>> x = [0, 0, 0, 3]  # should show up in counts1
    >>> o = [0, 0, 0, 0]  # should show up in counts2
    >>> out = [[x, o, o],
    ...        [x, x, x],
    ...        [o, o, x]]
    >>> counts1, counts2 = give_counts(out)
    >>> assert counts1 == 5
    >>> assert counts2 == 4
    """

    values = (True if col[3] > 0.5 else False for row in out for col in row)
    counts = collections.Counter(values)
    return counts[True], counts[False]
```

Comment: I'm new to python, never used this module. I add "from collections import Counter" but I have this error "NameError: name 'collections' is not defined". Probabally missing something, I will check.

Comment: try `import collections`. When you use the `from <module> import <name>` syntax you're importing just that name into your current namespace, so if you did `from collections import Counter`, you'd then do `Counter(values)` not `collections.Counter(values)`. Notably: either way would work :)

Comment: Changed for `Counter(values)` and worked but now I have thid error: `values = (True if col[3] > 0.5 else False for row in out for col in row)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` . I can print the values with `print(out[0 , 3, 0:12, 0:12])` but I need count the values

Comment: then your data structure is unclear to me. I understood `out[0][0][3]` to be the fourth element of the array you were looking for.